# Pass arguments to jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use jupyter Notebook and I run a function that needs arguments to run, how can I  pass arguments to the Main function with jupyter Notebook???

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example? It is not clear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Arguments given to the Jypyter server aren't passed through to the notebooks.  This has been discussed in previous SO questions.

Comment: @DanielLenz when i execut my code with ipython i do `$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3` but with jupyter i think there is auther way to do that

Comment: @hpaulj thinks for reply. could you please give me the link of question